# descargar archivo txt

Tags: php

Actualmente estoy utilizando este método para descargar una consulta realizada.

```
mostrar_flush(1,"Espere un momento por favor mientras se termina  la consulta 90%......");

$retorno[] = $ArrayPlanoCGUNO;
    $retorno[] = "06";
    $codigo_serialize= base64_encode(serialize($retorno));
/*  
    echo '<form  id="frm1" name="frm1" action="http://evoluciondigital.com.co/websaas/interfase/historico-publicaciones/" method="post"  target="_blank"> 
          <input type="hidden" value="' . $codigo_serialize . '" name="datos">                     
          </form>';*/
      $urlServer='http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

     echo '<form  id="frm1" name="frm1" action="'.$urlServer.'/interfase/index.php/historico-publicaciones/" method="post"  target="_blank"> 
             <input type="hidden" value="' . $codigo_serialize . '" name="datos">                     
             </form>'; 
    //Función que sirver para llamar el submit de el formulario y cargarse sin necesidad del boton enviar
    echo "<script>
          function formSubmit(){
            document.getElementById('frm1').submit();
          }
            formSubmit();
         </script>";

    terminar_flush(1);
    return true;
```

Pero no me permite descargar el archivo a txt y me carga el servidor.

¿Hay alguna forma para que sea mas optimo y no me genere tanto inconveniente?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta pero a simple vista, la variable que traes: $retorno[] = $ArrayPlanoCGUNO; lo borras con: $retorno[] = "06"; Sería muy bueno que dieras más detalles de tu pregunta. Ojala te haya servido.

Answer (score 1):

Imprime el texto y pon un header :

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="default-filename.txt"')
echo $variable;
```

Esto , crerá un pop-up en el navegador para que descarge en un formato txt , como en el ejemplo , el contenido de $variable.